# What is the purpose of app.use() in vueJS application?

Tags: node.js, vuejs3, vuex

I’ve been learning vue and im trying to understand what app.use() is used for is it anything similar to app.use in express?

I have looked at the vue he documentation and cannot find any helpfu information

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's for using vue plugins while in express it's registering middleware.
Here is the part of the docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html#introduction